# 'Rigify' with automatic weights makes my mesh disappear

Tags: rigging

I'm making a human character. I'm trying to rig it with rigify - but I don't think I'm doing it correctly, as when I press ctrl+p > with automatic weights it makes the mesh disappear.

The blend file is here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36983 
Also, a video and gif are on my Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7tsr5dv25253gv8/rigging.gif?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bv65dd1kzxkwwg1/rigging.mov?dl=0

Comment: Same Problem: if ... -> Bendybones -> Segments [above 1] (tell me if it solved for you, too)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have checked AUTO RUN PYTHON SCRIPTS in the User Preferences

Just go to File/User Preferences/File
and then check the box

☑️ 'Auto Run Python Scripts'

Comment: omg, I wasted so much time on this. Thank you for the clue!